# Как сделать прилипающий блок с помощью js?

Tags: javascript, css

Нужно чтобы блок прилипал к верху при скруле.
Как это реализовать? Если можно, дайте пример, пожалуйста.
Думаю, что нужно через функцию scrool делать и при достижении определённой высоты добавлять класс, но реализовать не получается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 100) {
    $('nav').addClass('fixed');
  } else {
    $('nav').removeClass('fixed');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}

header {
  background: #ccc;
  height: 100px;
}


section {
  min-height: 1000px;
}

nav {
  position: absolute; left: 0;
  top: 100px;
  background: #00f;  
  width: 100%;  
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 99;
}
nav.fixed {
  position: fixed; top: 0;
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>header</header>

<nav>Блок, который прилипает</nav>

<section>Контент</section>
```

Comment: Спасибо! То, что нужно. А как сделать так, чтобы блок доезжал до определённого места, например до футера, и дальше не уезжал?

Comment: в гугле по фразе scrollBottom поищите

Comment: Погуглил, но как применять к своему случаю - не пойму. Не могли бы вы подсказать, пожалуйста?

Comment: @Александр https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/bfb0v5vm/

Comment: Спасибо, но к сожалению не совсем то, что нужно. Мой блок изначально имеет позиционирование absolute, и должен липнуть при скруле. + он липнет к экрану, а мне нужно чтобы он оставался в пределах родителя.

Answer (score 0):

1. Вешаем обработчик на событие скрола
2. Проверяем состояние скрола
3. Если скрол больше нужного, то добавляем класс, в котором блоку задаётся `position:fixed`

```js
window.onscroll = function() {//событие скрола
  var scrolled = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  if(scrolled >= 200) document.getElementById("top-block").classList.add("fixed-top"); 
}
```

```css
#top-block{
    position:relative;
 }
#top-block.fixed-top{
   position:fixed;
   top:0;
   left:0;
 }
```

```html
<div id="top-block">content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Для решения подобной задачи я писал [jQuery-плагин](https://github.com/WEACOMRU/jquery.fixed), который применяет свойство `position: fixed;` к элементу когда страница прокручивается ниже его позиции. Также элементу добавляется класс-модификатор (по умолчанию `__fixed`), благодаря которому вы можете настроить внешний вид фиксированного элемента.

При это на месте целевого элемента размещается пустой элемент-заглушка, который предотвращает деформацию структуры страницы.

Использование:

```
$('.js-fixed').fixed(options);
```

С помощью настроек вы сможете задать собственный класс-модификатор и отступ от элемента, на котором его необходимо *"фиксировать"*. Подробнее об этом читайте на *GitHub*.

Однако, если вам нужно решение на ванильном JavaScript, придется приложить некоторые усилия, чтобы переписать плагин. Но я думаю, исходный код должен вам помочь в этом.

Comment: А с помощью этого плагина можно сделать так, чтобы сайдбар, например, скролился только до футера и не дальше?

Comment: @Александр такое поведение в нем не учитывалось, к сожалению